# Error on selecting value from dynamic picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, picklist

I am getting error while selecting value from a dynamic picklist. The picklist values are generated on form load by selecting the distinct values for a field in an object.

> Class

```
   public SET<SelectOption> distinctDomain {get;set;}
   /*To get the distinct values for the picklist for contact - Domain, City, Country*/
   public Set<SelectOption> getDistinctPicklistValues(){
        distinctDomain = new Set<SelectOption>();  
        for(Contact a : [select id,MailingCity, MailingCountry, Domain__c from Contact]){        
            distinctDomain.add(new SelectOption(a.Domain__c.trim(),a.Domain__c.trim()));
        }
        return distinctDomain;
   }
```

> Page

```
        <apex:outputText value="Pick List" styleClass="outputDec"/>
        <apex:selectList value="{!contactDomain}" multiselect="false" size="1" style="width:159px;">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!distinctDomain}"/>
                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="contactForm" oncomplete="jsPicklistClear();" action="{!fetchJobs}"/>  
        </apex:selectList>
```

**The error is thrown in the action support in VF Page. When I remove the action support I am getting no error. Also the code is not entering the function fetchJobs() because of the error thrown in action support.**

**Error:
j_id0:mainForm:j_id27:j_id31: Validation Error: Value is not valid**

Please find the screenshot shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The getter is called each time a form submit occurs. If the records that are queried change between form submits, you can cause this error to occur.

I would suggest that you only initialize the list inside the constructor or an action method, and always validate that the currently selected value matches one of the options from the list of options you generate.

Modifying a list like this in a getter or setter method is a sure-fire way to get unexpected results.

Finally, use should use a list instead of a set. The unordered nature of sets might also cause this problem, but I'd have to test that.

Query all the domains into a set of strings, then generate the list of select options from that set.

Comment: Hi Sfdc fox... I have added the getter here in this function just for the display. In my actual code it is defined in constructor.

Comment: As I said, the code is not reaching the function. You can check here http://notes.io/YQy   The function getDistinctPicklistValues()

Comment: Like I said, initialize your list in the constructor, and never from that getter. Thus can produce unreliable results. You don't even have a constructor that I could find (but, I'm mobile, so I might have missed it).

Comment: I think this is actually a lot simpler than I originally thought. Try <apex:selectOptions value="{!distinctPicklistValues}"/> instead.

Answer (score 0):

Visualforce is a cousin to JSF.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069379/validation-error-value-is-not-valid

It looks like you're trying to store a value in a picklist that does not exist as a selectable option for that picklist under normal circumstances.

Changing the field type to text is a possible workaround.

Comment: :P I cant edit field here to text.

Comment: Your other workaround would be to add all possible values as options to your picklist on the field itself.

Comment: its a text field and not a picklist field.. so I have have to fetch all distinct values and add it to a dynamic picklist variable and display it

Comment: As an aside, results from a query are always trim()'d. They never contain leading or taking spaces.